# Bootstrap 4 and css transform rotation

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I want to make a diamond with lines beside. It works when it's a square, but when I apply `transform: rotation(45deg);` on the square, the two lines are crossing the diamond.

https://jsfiddle.net/0kty2fLw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS transforms don't affect the position of any other elements. Initial sizes and positions of all elements are set before any CSS transforms are applied, then CSS transforms are applied, affecting only the transformed elements. This means that when your square is rotated 45 degrees, the lines on each side are still the same length they were before the rotation. After the transform, the rotated square is now wider than it was before the rotation, so the lines are overlapping the left & right points of your 'diamond'.

The quickest way to deal with this is to set a background colour (white would work with your example) on your square to cover the lines, and ensure the lines are set with `z-index` to go behind the rotated square. Alternatively, if you need the square/diamond to be transparent, you could reduce the width of the lines using the left & right margins to prevent the overlap.

As a side note, your Bootstrap structure is not correct: you shouldn't have a `.container` inside a `.container`. I would also avoid using Bootstrap grid elements for something like this. It adds unnecessary structural complexity to HTML that should be much more straightforward. If you need this to fit inside a Bootstrap layout, I'd just do the whole line / diamond design inside one full width `.col` and deal with the sizing & responsiveness independently.

Comment: Thank you for your very complete and informative answer. I am going to try your solution. What would you suggest other than bootstrap ? Simply use flexbox ? (I want this to be responsive)

Comment: No problem using Bootstrap in general, but it's not necessary (or really a good idea) to use the structural grid elements for something like this. I'd do it with a more minimal HTML approach, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xb9a8mk5/1/. If you want the square to be responsive, you can adjust that and the line widths with media queries.

Comment: Thank you, your code is much more readable and simple. I am going to study your code because I am not used to do CSS lol.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

check this.

```
#ligne1{
    margin-right: -5vw;
}

#ligne2{
    margin-left: -5vw;
}
```

It'll maintain the responsive design

Comment: I want lines beside the diamond (a line, the diamond, a line). But as you can see, when I transform the square into a diamond, the lines are a little bit crossing the diamond.

Comment: what do you mean by, beside?. like this ` |<>| ` ?

Comment: No, like this -<>-

Comment: Thank you very much Yoarthur but it is not working very well, t-jam solution is working

Answer (score 0):

Just increase left and right margin.
Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0kty2fLw/4/

```
#ligne1{
  margin-right: 35px;
}

#ligne2{
  margin-left: 35px;
}
```

And remove col-2 class

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row ">
  <div class="ligne col my-auto" id="ligne1"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="square my-auto">
          <div class="circle">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ligne col my-auto" id="ligne2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not responsive

Comment: Thank you !  But it is not working very well, t-jam solution is working